# cd to variable not working from batch

Tags: batch-file, cmd, cd

Please find below the batch script  :-

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
set /a count = 0
for /D %%i in (*) do (


        set /a count += 1
        echo !count! %%i
        cd \d %%i 
        echo "inside" %cd% " to execute some command"
        echo "some command"
        echo "now again going one directory back"
        cd ..

)
endlocal
```

execution of

> cd \d %%i

gives below error :-

> The system cannot find the path specified.

i want to go inside the directory that %%i represents, perform some command there, then want to go one directory back.

PFA screenshot of sample run.[image]

Comment: Consider using commands [`pushd`](http://ss64.com/nt/pushd.html) and [`popd`](http://ss64.com/nt/popd.html) rather than `cd`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `cd /d` not `cd \d`

`cd` will assume the directory you want to change to is `\d %%i`

Comment: Thanks Magoo for your quick reply. cd /d is also not working.

Comment: Sadly "not working" gives us no information to work on. If you mean `it's not apparently changing the directoryname displayed by the echo "inside"...` display, then you need to echo `!cd!` not `%cd%`. You only asked to cure the `The system cannot find the path specified` problem...

Comment: attached screenshot of a sample run

Comment: You are execution `cd /d %%i` and displaying `%%i` in your code. You should see that `%%i` is simply the directoryname, not the complete path. Therefore the correct `cd` destination should be `%cd%\%%i` Use `%cd%` as this is replaced by your starting directoryname during parsing, and you require this to be constant - `!cd!` would give you the directoryname as you change it. BTW - `cd ..` moves to the parent directory - perhaps what you mean by `one directory back`. I suggest you try `PUSHD "%cd%\%%i"` & `POPD` to return to the starting directory. Also beware of what will happen with for /d /r